# Efficient way to calculate number of strings which contain a defined shorter string

Tags: r

I have a character vector containing short strings:

```
short <- c("aaa", "bah", "dju", "kjs")
```

I want to count the number of strings in the following vector in which at least one of the above short strings is present.

```
long <- c("aaajhd", "slilduaaadifh", "sldifjsdbahsdofiusd", "sdflisjdjukjs", "sldifjbak", "sdfoiuwebss", "sdkfuhsd", "sdlfihwoio")
```

The number it should output for this is 4, as 4 of the strings in the `long` vector contain the shorter strings defined in the `short` vector.

My actual short vector is around 10000 strings and long is around 1000, so I am looking for an efficient way to calculate this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the 'short' vector, get the `str_count` and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector to get the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
sum(Reduce(`|`, lapply(short, str_count, string = long)))
#[1] 4
```

`str_count` uses the `stringi` functions and this don't depend on the `length` of the `vector`

Comment: I know I didn't ask this in the question, but how could I calculate the frequency of each of the `short` strings individually?

Comment: @JackArnestad  It should be `sapply(short, function(x) sum(str_count(long, x)))`

Answer (score 4):

This takes about 0.12 seconds on my laptop where `long` and `short` are from the Note at the end and have lengths 10000 and 1000.  No packages are used -- only to generate the sample data.

```
system.time(num <- length(grep(paste(short, collapse = "|"), long, perl = TRUE)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.08    0.00    0.12
```

In comparison the Reduce/str_count solution takes 6.5 seconds.

**Note:**   We take the first 1000 and 10000 words from the book Ulysses as the sample data.

```
library(gsubfn)

u <- "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4300/4300-0.txt"
joyce <- readLines(u)
joycec <- paste(joyce, collapse = " ") 
words <- strapplyc(joycec, "\\w+")[[1]]
short <- head(words, 1000)
long <- head(words, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes me only 0.09s with the data provided above.

```
system.time(sum(sapply(regmatches(long, gregexpr(paste(short, collapse = "|"), long, ignore.case = F, perl = T)), length) >= 1))
   User      System verstrichen 
   0.09        0.00        0.09
```

Data:

```
library(gsubfn)
u <- "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4300/4300-0.txt"
joyce <- readLines(u)
joycec <- paste(joyce, collapse = " ") 
words <- strapplyc(joycec, "\\w+")[[1]]
short <- head(words, 1000)
long <- head(words, 10000)
```